# Why is the Datastore Admin function not bulk deleting large numbers of entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the Datastore Admin functionality installed in my AppEngine Console.  I have several Entity Kinds that have over 100,000 entities each.  I need to clear out the existing entities and reload the data.  I have found using the Datastore Admin that:

1. Small numbers of entity deletes are fine.  Small being less that 20 entities.  I can run the Datastore Admin delete, the records are removed immediately and the Entities are removed from the Datastore Admin screen and the entity kinds can no longer be found in the datastore viewer.
2. For large Entity Kinds, greater than 100,000, the Datastore Admin delete jobs run fine and report no errors, but the Datastore Admin shows the exact same number of entities.  Thinking this may just be an issue with statistics not getting updated I used the Datastore Viewer and there is still data in each of the Entity Kinds that I tried to delete.

Because the Datastore View does not show a total number of records, I have no idea if some of the entities were actually deleted (at least not without manually paginating through thousands of pages of data.).

Does anyone have any ideas of what may be happening here?  I have tried writing my own delete programs in Java and run them as Backends looping through each Entity Kind and deleting records in batches of 50, but the system still shows statistics of entities still existing and the Datastore Viewer continues to show records.

Comment: Does the delete job finish before you check the admin viewer?

Comment: Datastore Admin isn't a live view on the Datastore contents (Viewer is, though). From personal experience Admin updates its stats once a day. The docs hint at this under the headline "Caveats on Using Data Admin Features": https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

Comment: The delete job does finish.  I'm not seeing errors in the logs.

Comment: In regards to the datastore admin not being a live view, what is odd is that when the record set is small (less than 20), then the deletes work and the stats update immediately.  I'm a little worried that for large datasets things are somehow queued up.  It seems more like AppEngine has just rejected the deletes because the viewer is still showing the data.

Comment: can you please add the code you are using for deletion.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using the Admin console, I deleted an entity that has 160k instances. I could see that the console had launched a map reduce job to delete my entity.  After a while, the console indicated that the delete job "completed". The dashboard shows 3.2 million datastore writes during the delete operation, and Google was nice enough to charge me $$ for these operations. But none of the entities are deleted as seen in the Datastore Viewer and from my application code....This is clearly a App Engine bug, but I'm not sure what triggered it (e.g. size, index).

Comment: Over 5 years later and I'm experience the same thing. I wrote a method that reads all the keys of the entities and then deletes them in batches of 500. All of my call to delete succeed without errors. I know that it can take a little time for Datastore to achieve consistency across all the indices so I give it a couple hours to complete the delete. Then I read all the entities out and count them expecting to read 0 entities. Instead I get back about half of the entities. Waiting longer doesn't seem to help. I can come back 3 or 4 hours later and there will still be the same number of records.